# Unity webGL - startup time

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a Unity WEBGL Project, which is about 130MB big. I think that is not that much.

On my PCs and MacBooks everything runs very fine and smooth. Startup time is about 10 sec.

But on some PCs it takes over 20 min to download (with 50Mbit/s), and then the game has a fps about 10-15.

I don't know what is causing this big loading times at the beginning on some PCs. They have all a good internet connection.

Can you maybe give me a tip or something, how to optimize this?

Thanks!

Comment: Both PC and internet speeds vary wildly. You cannot do much at your end in these cases.

Comment: Are all PC's using the same browser ?

Comment: Yes, but I tried it in different browsers. I am currently at the customers place and here it takes with my pc too long, too. 130 MB with 13Mbit shouldn't take over 18 minutes to finish.